# Cumulative sum minus mean with R

Tags: r

I am trying to subtract the cumulative sum of the previous values minus the mean based on my current position. For example I have:

```
A
1 
2
3 
4 
5
```

and i want this:

```
A B
1 NA
2 3-mean(A)
3 6-mean(A)
4 10-mean(A)
5 15-mean(A)
```

Comment: `cumsum(A)*(1 - 1/seq_along(A))`

Comment: @eddi you should probably post that...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want `NA` as the first value for the `B` column.  Here I use `1-mean(A)` instead:

```
> A <- 1:5
> data.frame(A=A, B=cumsum(A)-mean(A))
  A  B
1 1 -2
2 2  0
3 3  3
4 4  7
5 5 12
```

Comment: I think the OP needs the mean on the *current* position. Something similar to @eddis comment. Good to see you answering some questions again though :)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
x<-data.frame(a=1:6)
x %>%
 mutate(mycol=mean(a)-lag(cumsum(a),1))
  a mycol
1 1    NA
2 2   2.5
3 3   0.5
4 4  -2.5
5 5  -6.5
6 6 -11.5
```